# Ruby case expression unexpected keyword

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, include, gsub, case-expression

I am new to Ruby. My past is in Java. I am trying to use a switch case, apparently known as a case expression in Ruby. I want to accept user input, check that input to see if it includes certain characters, and then substitute  those characters with other characters. When I try to run this simple program I get many syntax errors but I am not sure why. Could someone please explain to me if I am using this statement wrong and if I can even use case expression in this situation? Thank you.

```js
    empty_string = true

    while empty_string do
    print "Pleathe enter a thtring: " 
    user_input = gets.chomp
    user_input.downcase!

      case
        when user_input.include? ("s")
            user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
        when user_input.include? ("ch")
            user_input.gsub!(/ch/, "th")
        when user_input == ""
            puts "You typed noting! You get nothing sir!"
        when user_input != ""
            empty_string = false
        else
            puts "There are no 's's in your string."
        end

    end

    puts "Zai jian, #{user_input}"
```

Below are the errors correlating by line and syntax error

**rb.rb:9**: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
    when user_input.include? ("s")

**rb.rb:11**: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
    when user_input.include? ("ch")
        ^

**rb.rb:13**: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
    when user_input == ""
        ^

**rb.rb:15**: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
    when user_input != ""
        ^
**rb.rb:17**: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end

**rb.rb:21**: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

BELOW IS THE FIXED CODE THANKS TO @Phlip

```js
empty_string = true

while empty_string do
print "Pleathe enter a thtring: " 
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

  case
    when user_input.include?("s")
        user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
        empty_string = false
    when user_input.include?("ch")
        user_input.gsub!(/ch/, "th")
        empty_string = false
    when user_input == ""
        puts "You typed noting! You get nothing sir!"
        empty_string = true
    else
        puts "There are no 's's in your string."
    end

end

puts "Zai jian, #{user_input}"
```

The issue was the spaces I had after .include?, @Phlip told me Ruby is space sensitive. I removed the white space and it worked. I ran into an issue with the boolean after and fixed that as well. It works as intended now.

Comment: `case user_input` should be just `case`, because each `when` has a complete boolean expression in it.

Comment: If that doesn't fix your syntax error, edit your post and add your error lines.

Comment: In addition to @Phlip's `case` suggestion, try adding parentheses around the `#include?` arguments (e.g. `user_input.include?("s")`).

Comment: if a `when` clause evaluates to `true`, then no other `when` clauses are evaluated.

Comment: @steenslag does it not matter that it is in the while loop?

Comment: @Phlip I tried removing user_input but still have the same errors,@Zoran I added parentheses but still same issue, I will edit and add error lines, and also show you the example of this working with if statements.

Comment: Ruby is space-sensitive. `user_input.include? ("s")` is different from `user_input.include?("s")`, without the space.

Comment: @Phlip Thank you! That was the issue. I then ran into another issue with my Boolean in the while loop but I was able to solve that. I will upload the working code. Thanks again.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for those recommendations. I will remove the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you wish to ask the user for a string until the string contains `"s"` or `"ch"`. When such a string is found you wish to make one or more substitutions in the string and print out a string containing the modified string. Here is a Ruby-like way of doing that.

```
user_input = nil
loop do
  print "Pleathe enter a thtring: " 
  user_input = "cheater" # gets.chomp.downcase

  case user_input
  when /s/
    user_input.gsub!('s','th')
    break
  when /ch/
    user_input.gsub!('ch','th')
    break
  when ""
    puts "You typed noting! You get nothing sir!"
  else
    puts "There are no 's's in your string."
  end
end

puts "Zai jian, #{user_input}"
```

If the user enters an empty string, `"You typed noting! You get nothing sir!"` and then `"Pleathe enter a thtring: "` are displayed and `gets` awaits another entry.

If the user enters a non-empty string that contains no `"s"`'s or `"ch"'s, "Pleathe enter a thtring: "` is displayed and `gets` awaits another entry.

If the user enters `"Chester\n"` `"Zai jian, chethter"` is diplayed.
If the user enters `"Cheater\N"` `"Zai jian, theater"` is displayed.

If you actually wish to replace all `"s"`'s and `"ch"`'s, substitute the following for the first two `when` statements.

```
when /s|ch/
  user_input.gsub!(/s|ch/,'th')
  break
```

If this is done and user enters `"Chester"` `"thethter"` is displayed. (The `when` line could instead be written `when /s/, /ch/`, but I don't like that as well, in part because `/s|ch/` is still needed as `gsub!`'s first argument.)

Note that case statements use the method [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).  We therefore see that `/s/.===(s) #=> true`. Ruby allows us to write that `/s/ === 'chester'` ("syntactic sugar").

`user_input = <anything>` must precede the loop to make its value visible after the loop.

See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). For other uses of this method the handling of `StopIteration` exceptions is very useful when working with enumerators (instances of the [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html) class).

`===` looks a lot like `==`, but they should be thought of as entirely different methods.